What is the solution of marking an old question as duplicate of a new question?
I asked this question more than 8 years ago on this site. However, this question did not get a good answer in my view, and that is why there is no accepted answer in it.
Around one year ago, the same question was asked here. The answerer, @UmH answered the question on the same day and got accepted.
Now, I found it today that my question is marked as duplicate by the answerer of the other question.
I am not blaming anyone, because, I hope, none did it intentionally. I am just drawing the attention of the community to how to resolve such an issue!
As I have asked the question first, I have more right to keep it on the platform, and the later one should be marked as a duplicate. That is the motto of duplicating, right? Otherwise, I or other people would be deprived or discouraged from asking good questions first.

I don't see any issue here, but let me try to explain.
First of all, your question is very specific and since it is about the Eid prayer. While the question which was marked as a duplicate is more general about praying in a mosque. And essential for marking your question a duplicate the proposed answer addresses your inquiry.
Secondly, the answer of your question was not accepted by you while the answer of the duplicate was accepted.
The community bot's logical conclusion, once it was marked as a duplicate by any user, was therefore to mark your question as a duplicate (and maybe suggest you to do so, if you accepted then you've closed it as a duplicate yourself).
In our help page in the section about questions marked as duplicate you may read:

The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. This does not mean that every duplicate will immediately be closed; we love (some) dupes. There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way.

Marking a question as duplicate is not a degradation of a question, since different people would address, express or formulate a topic differently, but the intention of marking a question a duplicate is to help people find the answer that addresses their question.
If you disagree you are free to re-formulate your question and point out why you disagree with the duplicate marking.
From my perspective, there is a reason, for example in the Maliki school of fiqh the Eid prayer is not recommended to be performed in a mosque, but on an open ground which is referred to as "al-Musalla", since it is the objective of this prayer to gather all people of a city and its surroundings. It is only allowed to pray it in a mosque under specific conditions like the case of rainy weather.

It is valid to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one or vice versa. See Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?
Note that being marked as a duplicate will not remove your question from the platform, unless it fulfills some other automatic deletion criterion, see: How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion? So your question, reputation  you earned from it, and any traffic that it attracts in the future will be retained. It is just that a notice is added to your question to help other people find the answer to it.
In the given case I suggested (or voted) to close the question and it was then closed by the Community Bot, which (AFAIK) happens when the author (you) agreed to close it when it was suggested to you by the website. The reason that I suggested closing it was because the other question was more general and had an answer to your question. I did not consider the age of the question nor do I think that it matters, closing it this way made sense to me and closing it the other way around would also have been alright if your question had been properly answered.
